# rails search nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i try to search something in my objet calendar but all the time when i click on submit i get this error.
And i dont really understand why ?

***The request method POST is inappropriate for the URL /.***

_search.html.erb

```
<%= form_for user_calendars_path([@user, @calendar]), :method => 'get'  do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search_condition], :id => 'search_field' %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search" %> 
     <p>hello </p>
<% end %>
```

calendar_controller

```
 def index
    @search = @user.calendar.search(params[:search_condition])
    @content_calendars = @user.calendar.all
    @content_calendars_by_dates = @content_calendars.group_by(&:published_on)
    @date = params[:date] ? Date.parse(params[:date]) : Date.today
  end
```

route.rb

```
resources :users do
resources :calendars
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= form_tag user_calendars_path(@user, @calendar), :method => 'get'  do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search_condition], :id => 'search_field' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %> 
    <p>hello </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: if i try that i get No route matches {:controller=>"calendars"}. Why i need to use form_tag because by default form_tag use post and not get ?

Comment: Hi zyriuse, according to your routes you should define CalendersController. And form_tag is because you are not using any attributes which are dependent form_builder, and generally we used form_for for the object.

Comment: how i can define CalendarsController ? thanks for your explication about form_tag and form_for

Comment: your file name is calendar_controller, and i think it should be calendars_controller.rb, and controller should be definded like:
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
end